# In Stata, how can I append to a local varlist during a loop?

Tags: list, stata

I am trying to run multiple regressions where, on each iteration, another independent variable is added to the regression on each loop?

```
local vlist0 foo bar dar
local vlist1

foreach item in `vlist0'
    [add `item' to `vlist1']
    regress dependentVar `vlist1'
```

I can't seem to find any documentation on appending to local varlists or anything relating to this, so your help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some technique:

```
local vlist0 foo bar dar

local vlist1
foreach item of local vlist0 {
    local vlist1 `vlist1' `item'
    display "`vlist1'"
}
```

This appends the contents of the local, along with the new item, to the local itself.

Notice what this really does: redefine `local vlist1` each time around the loop. The new definition is the previous definition, plus the new `item`.
The first time around the loop `vlist1` is empty, but that is not illegal and is well-behaved.